# What format is this date? [17/6/2015 5:50:22 5 -120]

Tags: java, date, format, apache-pig

Context: Getting date from a third party data source as below. I am using Pig script to transform this string to date.

Script:

```
a= LOAD '/user/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t');  
b= FOREACH a GENERATE $0 as post_t_time_info; 
c= FOREACH b GENERATE ToDate(post_t_time_info,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss e ZZZ')
```

Sample value the date object takes:

```
17/6/2015 5:50:22 5 -120
17/6/2015 0:7:6 5 240
```

I am unable to understand what is -120/240. I tried with timezone(ZZZ) and milliseconds (SSS) but appears to be incorrect.

My current format used is 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss e X', where X is unknown and looking forward for appropriate pattern for it.

Thanks!

Reference: 
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Time_Zone_Fallback

Comment: How do you know it's not a timezone offset?

Comment: If I use ZZZ, I get error " Invalid format: "17/6/2015 1:15:43 5 240" is malformed at "240"

Comment: @CoDEmanX: Is timezone offset different from pattern Z? Please let me know

Comment: Context please?  Are you writing with ICU? ICU4C or ICU4J? Please tag your question with ICU and the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Also - are you saying you have written code that produces that output when you use that format? Or are you just trying to identify the format in isolation?  Please clarify.

Comment: Also - June 17, 2015 is a Wednesday.  If `5` is supposed to be the day of the week (matching ICU's `e`) then how is it 5?  Your locale's week would have to start on a Saturday.  What locale are you using?, and why do you have the weekday as a number in the middle of the string? Quite odd...

Comment: The example given in the ICU docs for `ZZZ` is `-0800`, but your value appears to be a timezone offset in minutes, **without padding**. I'm not sure if `Z` and `ZZ` are equivalent to `ZZZ`, if yes than the format isn't supported in its current form. You might wanna transform it to an ISO 8601 string first: `2015-06-17T05:50:22-0200`

Comment: @MattJohnson: I could be wrong with "e" pattern too. But pattern e appears to take the value sent after :ss appropriately.

Comment: I would ignore the `5` unless it has some other meaning explained by the source.  The day of week is deterministic by the supplied date, so it's extraneous information.  Though if `5` means something else, then you might need it. Best to ask your source and find out.

Comment: RFC 822 does not allow timezone offsets in minutes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone JavaScript's getTimezoneOffset() returns the difference in minutes, but `Z` only parses the hour:minute format.

Comment: I got information that 5 is the Day of week. 17/6/2015 refers to date 17 from July month as Jan month denoted as 0, feb 1 and so on. Also, the last 3 digits are timezone offset in minutes(difference  between UTC and local time) as Matt correctly described. I am writing a custom Java code to take this date string and convert into date object. Joda time/simple dateformat- both of them need a pattern to be defined. Both of these pattern seems to use 1 for referring Jan month. I am unclear which one to use for getting correct month and offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that `-120` and `240` are indeed time zone offsets.  They are likely in terms of minutes, not hours.  However, there's no standard for that, so it could be minutes *east* of GMT, or minutes *west* of GMT.

In other words, `-120` could be `UTC+02:00`, or `UTC-02:00`.  `240` could be `UTC+04:00`, or `UTC-04:00`.

For example, if it was obtained from the JavaScript `Date` object's `getTimezoneOffset` function, the sign will be opposite of what you might expect.  It would have positive values to the *west*, while the usual ISO8601 convention has positive values to the *east*.

Since you are the one obtaining the data, you are in a much better position than us to identify the source and disambiguate.  If it's from a third-party, look in their specs, or contact them and ask.

Also - You said you were using Apache Pig, but according to [their documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#to-date), the `ToDate` function uses Java's `SimpleDateFormat` - which does not use the same format qualifiers as ICU, nor does it have a format qualifier that recognizes time zone offsets in terms of minutes.  You will likely need to write your own function instead of using just the built-in `ToDate`.